# Ruby on Rails - trying to set up metatags and getting a simple HTML syntax error

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, syntax-error

I am trying to add some social tags.  Specifically Tweet as well as current number of tweets, Facebook recommend and current number of recommendations etc).

I have set up a partial app/views/aplication/_ogmeta.html.erb 
currently only has one line

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<%= meta.title ? DrillInvestor %>">
// also need type, image, and url
```

Which I reference in app/views/layout/application.html.erb

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

     <% ogdata = content_for?(:ogdata) ?  yield(:ogdata) : {} %>
     <%= render( partial: "ogmeta", locals: {meta: ogdata} ) %>  

     <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Drill Investor" %></title>
     <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script><![endif]-->
     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Getting syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ':'
from the line

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing the return value of when `meta.title` is nil in your ternary operator.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<%= meta.title ? DrillInvestor %>">
```

It should be something like:

```
<meta property="og:title" content='<%= meta.title ? meta.title : "DrillInvestor" %>'>
```

Comment: thanks- unfortunately this gives error "undefined method `title' for {}:Hash "

Comment: When I remove all content from app/views/aplication/_ogmeta.html.erb I get no cimple errors.

Answer (score 0):

Tristian Smith suggested the following:
1- Change app/views/appllication/_ogmeta.html.erb to

```
<meta property="og:title" content='<%= meta[:title] || "DrillInvestor" %>'>
```

2- change app/views/layouts/application.htl.erb to

```
<head>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <% ogdata = content_for?(:ogdata) ?  yield(:ogdata) : Hash.new %>
  <%= render "ogmeta", meta: ogdata %>

  <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Drill Investor" %></title>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script><![endif]-->
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

thanks 
Pierre